# Eclipse IDE - Standard and Enterprise editions

Tags: eclipse

If I already have Eclipse Enterprise Edition on my PC, do I need to install Eclipse SE or is it included within Eclipse EE?

**Edit:**

What is the difference between **Eclipse Standard** and **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** edition

Comment: It's hard to know for sure what you have and what you're asking about. Eclipse doesn't have an "Enterprise Edition" (the closest thing would be Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" I guess), nor is there an "Eclipse SE" (the closest thing might be "Eclipse Standard" I guess).

Comment: Yes, I have mixed up the terminology but that is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** is a superset of **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**, so the short answer is that you don't need to install them both.

You can see the contents of each package by clicking its name on the downloads page. You can also use the compare page that @Chandrayya mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! "Superset" was the ideal word I was looking for.

Comment: If a response answers your question please Accept it so appropriate credit is given. You can also up-vote responses that are useful but not complete answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its included but the sources of **Java Development Tools** and **Plug-in Development Environment** were not included.

Go to this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) here you can compare the packages included in standard and enterprise editions.

Comment: I am not clear about what you mean by "Plug-in Development Environment" but thank you for the link!